# Multiplying radicals by variables

Tags: radicals

Let's say I am to multiply $3x^2$ by ${\sqrt 8}$.
 Which answer is true and why?

> $3 {\sqrt 8x^2}$

or

> $3x^2 {\sqrt 8}$

Comment: The two are mathematically the same, so they are technically both true. However, the first form is the one commonly used, since it groups the constants together $3 \sqrt{8}$ and separates the variable $x^2$ at the end.

Comment: @dxiv how come is $x^2$ separated as it's multiplied with $8$ under the square root?

Comment: Where do you see $x^2$ *under* the square root? $\;3\sqrt{8}\,x^2  = 3\sqrt{8} \cdot x^2 \ne 3 \sqrt{8 x^2}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, I was so confused as I thought both $8$ and $x^2$ are under the square root. Thanks, now I get it)

Comment: I have seen the second form.  I believe it's for clarity's sake.  The idea being to clearly differentiate between $3\sqrt8x^2$ and $3\sqrt{8x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the same.

You can use the following laws.

For all reals $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have $$ab=ba$$ and
$$(ab)c=a(bc).$$
Now, let $3=a$, $\sqrt8=b$ and $x^2=c$.

Thus, $$3\sqrt8x^2=abc=(ab)c=a(bc)=a(cb)=acb=3x^2\sqrt8$$

Comment: What about this same scenario except 3 doesn't exist: multiplying $x^2$ by $\sqrt 8$. Can I write the product as $x^2\sqrt8$ or it must be written as $\sqrt 8x^2$ ?

Comment: @Steve They are the same again. You need to choose what is more comfortable for you. I like $x^2\sqrt8$, but I know that there are people which like $\sqrt8x^2$.